# If $c \leq \frac{a_i}{b_i} \forall i$, then $c \leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i}$

Tags: statistics, inequality, arithmetic, fractions

I'm trying to prove that the best moment tail bound is no worse than the best Chernoff bound. I have all pieces other than this little frustration here:

if $\forall i, c \leq \frac{a_i}{b_i}$, then it follows that $c \leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i}$.

My intuition is that both summations in numerator and denominator act as averages for $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s respectively, and thus $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i}$ could be no smaller than $\min \{\frac{a_i}{b_i}\}$. There must be something really basic that I must have overlooked...so thanks for the heads up in advance!

Comment: Are $c, a_i, b_i$ positive ?

Comment: do the limits exist? (is the denominator non-zero?) hint is: multiply by the denominator

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all numbers are positive and that the series are convergent, you have
$$cb_i \le a_i$$ for all $i$.
Hence, summing all up, you have 
$$c\sum_i b_i \le \sum_i a_i$$ which is equivalent to $$c \le \frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}$$

Comment: Oh well...I overthink way too much. Thanks a ton!